# Delete all rows in which a field value matches in both datasets

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have two queries. I need to produce a third query which deletes all the rows where Child Name is found in both.  So, if  [Child Not Seen_Pull].[Child_Name] matches in [Child Seen_Pull].[Child_Name] in the new query the rows which meet the criterion (Matching Names) are removed. I am new to Access so I'm not sure how to write that in Access SQL.

****Query 1 [Child Not Seen_Pull] ****

```
SELECT [Child Not Seen_Clean].ID, [Child Not Seen_Clean].[Case ID], [Child Not Seen_Clean].Child_Name, [Child Not Seen_Clean].[Worker Site / Unit], [Child Not Seen_Clean].[Worker Name], [Child Not Seen_Clean].[Worker Role], [Child Not Seen_Clean].[Contact Date], [Child Not Seen_Clean].[Contact Method], [Child Not Seen_Clean].[Contact Result], [Child Not Seen_Clean].Focus, [Child Not Seen_Clean].Participant
FROM [Child Not Seen_Clean]
WHERE ((([Child Not Seen_Clean].[Contact Method])<>"Face To Face") AND (([Child Not Seen_Clean].Participant)<>"Yes")) OR ((([Child Not Seen_Clean].[Contact Method]) Is Null)) OR ((([Child Not Seen_Clean].[Contact Method])="Face to Face") AND (([Child Not Seen_Clean].[Contact Result])="Attempted")) OR ((([Child Not Seen_Clean].[Contact Method])="Face to Face") AND (([Child Not Seen_Clean].[Contact Result])="Contacted") AND (([Child Not Seen_Clean].Focus)="Yes") AND (([Child Not Seen_Clean].Participant)="No")) OR ((([Child Not Seen_Clean].[Contact Method])="Phone") AND (([Child Not Seen_Clean].[Contact Result])="Contacted") AND (([Child Not Seen_Clean].Focus)="Yes")) OR ((([Child Not Seen_Clean].[Contact Method])="Fax") AND (([Child Not Seen_Clean].[Contact Result])="Contacted") AND (([Child Not Seen_Clean].Focus)="Yes")) OR ((([Child Not Seen_Clean].[Contact Method])="Phone") AND (([Child Not Seen_Clean].[Contact Result])="Attempted") AND (([Child Not Seen_Clean].Focus)="Yes")) OR ((([Child Not Seen_Clean].[Contact Method])="Mail") AND (([Child Not Seen_Clean].[Contact Result])="Attempted"))
ORDER BY [Child Not Seen].[ID];
```

**Query 2**

```
SELECT [Child Not Seen_Clean].[ID], [Child Not Seen_Clean].[Case ID], [Child Not Seen_Clean].Child_Name, [Child Not Seen_Clean].[Worker Site / Unit], [Child Not Seen_Clean].[Worker Name], [Child Not Seen_Clean].[Worker Role], [Child Not Seen_Clean].[Contact Date], [Child Not Seen_Clean].[Contact Method], [Child Not Seen_Clean].[Contact Result], [Child Not Seen_Clean].Focus, [Child Not Seen_Clean].Participant
FROM [Child Not Seen_Clean]
WHERE ((([Child Not Seen_Clean].[Contact Method])="Face To Face") AND (([Child Not Seen_Clean].[Contact Result])<>"Attempted") AND (([Child Not Seen_Clean].Participant)="Yes"))
ORDER BY [Child Not Seen].[ID];
```

Answer (score 0):

This is rather simple. Save the two queries that generate the IDs. Then create a new DELETE query. Replace a and b with your table names, or better yet, right click each table, change the alias to a or b, then click OK.

```
DELETE a.*
FROM a JOIN b ON a.ID = b.ID;
```

Comment: Thanks! I am getting an error messages which says "syntax error" this is my code below.  DELETE 
a.*, 
*
FROM Child Not Seen_Pull a  JOIN Child Seen_Pull b 
ON a.[Child Not Seen_Clean].Child_Name = b.[Child Not Seen_Clean].Child_Name;

Comment: I am also confused with the ID part. How do I assign a unique ID number to each name which matches in both datasets. There can be multipal rows with the same child name value in each data set

Comment: The answer to your first question is I had made a typo and fixed it in my edit (no ,* needed). The answer to your 2nd question depends on your data. I think I would need to see a sample of both tables to better understand what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your requirements correctly then the following query should do what you want:

```
DELETE FROM [Child Not Seen_Clean]
WHERE ID IN
    (
        SELECT [Child Not Seen_Pull].ID
        FROM 
            [Child Not Seen_Pull]
            INNER JOIN
            [Child Seen_Pull]
                ON [Child Not Seen_Pull].Child_Name=[Child Seen_Pull].Child_Name
        UNION
        SELECT [Child Seen_Pull].ID
        FROM 
            [Child Seen_Pull]
            INNER JOIN
            [Child Not Seen_Pull]
                ON [Child Seen_Pull].Child_Name=[Child Not Seen_Pull].Child_Name
    )
```

As always, be sure to make a backup copy of your data before experimenting with a DELETE query, just in case it does not do what you really intended.